# Ajax modals error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

This is what I tried so far by using Ajax. The Issue is that I get back  alert ("Something went wrong!"). I can't find the solution.

**Index.php**

```
<?php
  require_once 'core/init.php';
  include 'includes/head.php';
  include 'includes/navigation.php' ;
  include 'includes/headerfull.php';
  include 'includes/leftbar.php';

  $sql ="SELECT * FROM products WHERE featured = 1 ";
  $featured = $db->query($sql);

?>



<!---Main content--->
<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="row">
<h2 class="text-center">Izdvojeni Proizvodi</h2>
<?php while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)) : ?>

<div class="col-md-3">
  <h4><?= $product['title']; ?> </h4>
  <img src="<?= $product['image']; ?>" alt="<?= $product['title']; ?> " 
class="img-thumb" />
  <p class ="list-price text-danger"> List Price <s>$<?= $product 
['list_price'];?></s></p>
  <p class="price">Naša Cijena: $<?= $product ['price'];?></p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" onclick 
="detailsmodal(<?= $product ['id']; ?>)">Details </button>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>

 </div>
 </Div>

<?php
 include 'includes/rightbar.php';
 include 'includes/footer.php';
?>
```

**Footer.php**

```
</div>
<footer class ="text-center" id="footer">&copy; Copyright 2017-2018 Lodi  
</footer>

<script>

function detailsmodal(id) {
var data = {"id" : id} ;
jQuery.ajax({
url : 'includes/detailsmodal.php',
method : "post" ,
data : data,
success : function(data){
jQuery ('body').append(data);
jQuery ('#details-modal').modal('toggle');
},
 error: function (){
alert ("Something went wrong!");
 }
 });

}
</script>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as 
needed -->
<script 
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>


  </body>
  </html>


    </body>
    </html>
```

**Details modal.php**

```
 <!--Details Modal --->
 <? ob_start(); ?>
 <div class="modal fade details-1" id="details-modal" tabindex="-1" 
 role="dialog" aria-labelledby="details-1" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class ="modal-dialog modal-lg">
 <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header">
 <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
 <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
 </button>
 <h4 class="modal-title text-center">Levis Jeans</h4>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body">
 <div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6">
 <div class="center-block">
 <img src="images/headerlogo/levis.jpg" alt="Levis Jeans" class="details img-responsive">
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6">
 <h4>Details </h4>
 <p>These jeans are amazing! They are straight leg,fit great and look sexy.
 </p>
<hr>
<p>Price: $34.99</p>
<p>Brand: Levis</p>
<form action="add_cart.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-xs-3">
         <label for="quantity"> Quantity: </label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity">


     </div>
     <p>Availabe: 3</p>
   </div><br><br>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for ="size">Size:</label>
        <select name="size" id="size" class="form-control">
         <option value=""></option>
         <option value="28">28</option>
         <option value="32">32</option>
         <option value="36">36</option>
        </select>
    </div>
 </form>

 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
 <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
 <button class="btn btn-warning" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon 
 glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>Add To Cart</button>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <?php echo ob_get_clean(); ?>
```

**init.php**

```
 <?php

 $db= mysqli_connect('sql***.byethost11.com','****','****','ecom24database');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo'Database connection failed with following errors: ' . mysqli_connect_error();
 die();

}

define ('BASEURL','/ECOMDva');
```

I have already set up a database for navigation bar and modals products.
You can see the error on the website here : 
http://incloudme.byethost11.com/?i=2

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have visited your website running in Bytehost (freehosting), You have a 403 **403 Access denied** error on **Details modal.php** this might be because some free hosting denies permissions files for ajax request please change the folder permission to **755**  [image: plese see this] 
and next time write your ajax error function like this will alert you the error occurred

```
function detailsmodal(id) {
var data = {"id" : id} ;
jQuery.ajax({
url : 'includes/detailsmodal.php',
method : "post" ,
data : data,
success : function(data){
jQuery ('body').append(data);
jQuery ('#details-modal').modal('toggle');
},
 error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){                    
                   alert("fail"+errorThrown);
 }
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. I've been using windows, and uploaded the files with FilleZilla. I am not sure where do I change the folder permission. The server responded with a error (Forbidden) with this function

Comment: http://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/wordpress/navigation-customization/how-to-change-file-permissions-using-filezilla-on-your-ftp-site/ please follow these instructions and change the folder permissions to 755

Comment: I have tried using Cpanel , Chmod and now Filezilla, but it is still Forbidden

Comment: Check your htaccess file

Comment: The file was never existing, so I created .htaccess file with permission of 755 and DirectoryIndex index.php. But no changes

Comment: Can you try this programme on localhost than on a server ?? or you can forward me the src or the host credentials so i can look into it

Comment: You are right, this code works perfectly with Localhost, so the issue must be somewhere in hosting service...

Comment: Try 00webhost or any good php hosting i used free hosting.com before now i have got cpanel hosting from various hosting service

Answer (score 0):

Load jquery.min.js file before bootstrap.min.js.Like :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well it was before bootstrap.min.js as you can see inside footer.php , this doesn't work